# Should I put my logic in the underlying SQL query or in the SSRS report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

In our organisation, we create a number of reports requested by users / managers and publish them on an SSRS webpage.

We tend to create an SQL procedure which returns the desired results and we call that procedure in the SSRS dataset. We then use SSRS to present this in a nice looking table and tend to create groupings etc and put graphs in etc so that it looks presentable to the user.

Any "calculated columns" such as "Age" (which would be calculated from a date of birth and the current date) or "Average sales" (calculated from a total amount / a number of sales) are calculated in the underlying SQL procedure.

SSRS has a number of functions that allow these calculated columns to be calculated in the SSRS report itself.

My question really is, "What are the advantages of creating calculated columns in the underlying dataset vs creating them in SRRS?" is there any kind of performance hit? Are there other factors we should maybe think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine performance isn't a massive concern unless you are doing lots of huge calculations, I can't comment on that to any huge degree.

The advantages mostly come from allowing a report designer to create reusable expressions by creating fields in the dataset instead of having to create these as expressions in the report itself.

This is easier to maintain and easier to view. In SSRS 2008 or later, you can see the name of the field in each placeholder - this makes it much easier for a designer to work out what the result of each field will be.

If you use an expression, all you see in those boxes is `<<expr>>`, plus if you use this same expression in multiple places, you need to update the expression in all of those places if you decide to change how the value is calculated.

It's simply an extension of the DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, it seems like your answer is based on one developer creating a dataset and another developer creating the report? It makes more sense in that context as, like you say the dataset developer can ensure the calculation is correct at the dataset end. 

In our organisation, the dataset tends to be the same person as the report developer which is maybe why I haven't thought of it that way

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with relational databases as a source and you have control over the SQL being executed to return the data set, I would generally advise putting the logic for calculations, data type conversion etc. in the SQL and thereby offload the processing for that to the database engine which will usually be much more efficient at that than the report server.

I normally aim for the report to be a "presentation layer" which applies the formatting, layout, grouping and sorting to the data. The business logic that creates the underlying dataset is encapsulated in the query or procedure that is runs on the database. SSRS certainly does include a lot of functions that enable manipulation of data but I would normally only use these when the data source itself didn't support them. However if I was building a report which had some dynamic capability (e.g. report has a parameter that allows user to control how grouping is done in the report) then it might make sense to do the calculations in SSRS to make better use of caching.